# JSONB: How do I find all records which has keys in attribute with name "2" or "23"?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSONB hash structure in an attribute called `data`. I'm trying to figure out how I can find all records which has a key-name of EITHER "1" OR "23" among the keys in the hash?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6f261/2

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found a solution using `jsonb_object_keys`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6f261/1